# how java logger see the files where they get called

Tags: java, logging, classname

I'm building a logger for school.

I want to have these result in my file log.txt when I call

```
myLog.log("store that",level.ERROR);
```

log.txt:

```
"date-hour-<Class>-ERROR-store that"
```

I can have everything I want ( date, hour, ... ) except the `<Class>`.

For example if I call

```
myLog.log("store that",level.ERROR);
```

in a class named Cat, I would have something like this in log.txt:

```
"date-hour-Cat-ERROR-store that"
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: are you using some logging library or just java.util.logging?

Comment: `Cat.class.getSimpleName()` will give you the class name, but you should initialize your logger with the class

Comment: Did you roll your own logger? Make a new method that takes a class as well and use `getSimpleName()` like @kartik advises.

Comment: Nearly all logging systems use something like `LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThisClass.class);` for this.

Comment: I m using  my  own  logger. I thought to do mylogger.log ( this.class.getSimpleName ) . But if I use the logger  from other library, I don't have to specify this parameter.  I would call my logger method without specify manually the Emit class

Comment: My friends call their logger as you said, MyLogger.log ( this.class.getSimpleName (), logMessage ). It's doing the work, but I would know if it exists something giving the same result, but just  using MyLogger.log ( logMessage )

Comment: I m using factory and singleton pattern so I have a loggerFactory ( a simple one) with one method "createLogger" maybe it helps to find a solution